# MKMapView: getting latiude and longitude for a point

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I'm developing an **iPhone application** and I want to know the location on a MkMapView where the user has touch.

I have a MKMapView that fills the screen. When the user touch over the map, I need to know the location of the point the user has touched. Is that possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the instance method `convertPoint:toCoordinate`.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

Comment: It seems to be what I'm looking for. I'm going to try it and I'll tell you.